# Algorithm + ES6 - Compare 4 arrays of Objects and remove all repeated items

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I am trying to delete all repeated objects between four arrays by preference. All the arrays have unique elements, and may not be ordered. Here is a picture that tries to explain the problem:

[image]

As you can see, if the array has a lower preference, the elements will stay inside it. For example, the object with id "6" is repeated in the arrays with preference 2, 3, and 4. So, the algorithm has to detect this and remove these objects from the arrays with preference 3 and 4, because 2 < 3 < 4.

So, if the input data is:

```
  arr_p1 = [{ id: "892d" }, {id: "kla8x" }, {id: "sys32" }]
  arr_p2 = [{id: "saa1" }, { id: "892d" }]
  arr_p3 = [{ id: "kla8x" }, {id: "saa1" }, {id: "pp182" }]
```

the output must be:

```
  arr_p1 = [{ id: "892d" }, {id: "kla8x" }, {id: "sys32" }]
  arr_p2 = [{id: "saa1" }]
  arr_p3 = [{id: "pp182" }]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this situation in a good complexity order?

All arrays have a limited size of 40 objects.

The only thing I can think of is to sort all the objects, in each array, by identifier. Then, take the lowest identifier of an object moving with the pointer of each list, from the lowest preference (1) to the highest (4), and if it is in one of the higher preference lists, delete it... but I need to do it without altering the order of the elements ...

Pd: I am using JS and ES6.

Comment: Is the number of arrays fixed?

Comment: Do you have more data than this id in objects ?

Comment: Yes, the number of arrays is fixed, and no, the unique data is the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine all items to a single array, and then reduce them to a Map in a reversed order using `Array.reduceRight()`. The reversed order will cause the 1st items to override the last items.

Now you can filter each array by using the Map, and keeping only items that exist on the Map.

Complexity is O(N1 + N2 + N3) where Nx is the length of that array.

```js
const arr_p1 = [{ id: "892d" }, {id: "kla8x" }, {id: "sys32" }]
const arr_p2 = [{id: "saa1" }, { id: "892d" }]
const arr_p3 = [{ id: "kla8x" }, {id: "saa1" }, {id: "pp182" }]

// create an array of all items and reduce it in a reversed order to a Map
const dupsMap = [...arr_p1, ...arr_p2, ...arr_p3]
  // create the Map by using the `id` as the key, and the object as the value
  .reduceRight((acc, o) => acc.set(o.id, o), new Map())
  
const filterArr = arr => arr.filter(o =>
  dupsMap.get(o.id) === o // keep the item if it was the object that was used as value
)
  
const arr_p1f = filterArr(arr_p1)
const arr_p2f = filterArr(arr_p2)
const arr_p3f = filterArr(arr_p3)

console.log({ arr_p1f, arr_p2f, arr_p3f })
```

You can easily create a generic function that can handle any number of arrays, and get the individual arrays from it's returned value using destructuring.

```js
const dedupArrays = (...arrs) => {
  const dupsMap = arrs.flat() // convert arrays to a single array
    // a reduce right to create a Map of [id, object]
    .reduceRight((acc, o) => acc.set(o.id, o), new Map())
    
  // map the array of arrays, and filter each sub array
  return arrs.map(arr => arr.filter(o => dupsMap.get(o.id) === o))
}

const arr_p1 = [{ id: "892d" }, {id: "kla8x" }, {id: "sys32" }]
const arr_p2 = [{id: "saa1" }, { id: "892d" }]
const arr_p3 = [{ id: "kla8x" }, {id: "saa1" }, {id: "pp182" }]

const [arr_p1f, arr_p2f, arr_p3f] = dedupArrays(arr_p1, arr_p2, arr_p3)

console.log({ arr_p1f, arr_p2f, arr_p3f })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a preference object (hash map) to map the id to preference. Run it from 3rd array to the first so that lower order overrides the higher one.

Then when you have the preference map, you can filter all arrays by checking if the id's preference matches the current array.

```js
let arr_p1 = [{ id: "892d" }, {id: "kla8x" }, {id: "sys32" }];
let arr_p2 = [{id: "saa1" }, { id: "892d" }];
let arr_p3 = [{ id: "kla8x" }, {id: "saa1" }, {id: "pp182" }];

let pref = {};

arr_p3.forEach(e => pref[e.id] = 3);
arr_p2.forEach(e => pref[e.id] = 2);
arr_p1.forEach(e => pref[e.id] = 1);

arr_p1 = arr_p1.filter(e => pref[e.id] === 1);
arr_p2 = arr_p2.filter(e => pref[e.id] === 2);
arr_p3 = arr_p3.filter(e => pref[e.id] === 3);

console.log(arr_p1);
console.log(arr_p2);
console.log(arr_p3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have several tips for you, rather than a full answer, since I assume this is a homework question?

### Strategy

#### Build a set of "items already seen"

Check each new array against that, deleting any duplicate entries (in the new array).

#### Start with the most preferred array

That way, whenever something is deleted, it is being deleted from the less-preferred array.

For example, in pseudocode

```
let elementsSeen = new Set(   most preferred array of elements   )

for array in listOfArraysInDecreasingOrderOfPreference {

  for element in array {
    if element is in elementsSeen, delete it from array
  }
  elementsSeen = union of elementsSeen and array
}
```

### Complexity

Every item has to be looked at. It has to be compared with every other item, but the complexity of that need not be enormous, because the `Set` process can make use of hashes, i.e. not have to do an individual comparison of each incoming object with each existing object. Almost all incoming objects will have a hash table value that is different from those of existing objects, which is quick, at the expense of some time spent on hashing and some memory spent on the table.

In the worst case, where hashing is no longer helping you, it is O(N x M) where N is the number of arrays, and M is the size of each.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies you want to mutate the original arrays.

So if you still want to mutate the arrays you could.

1. create a SET of the ID's for each level.
2. Loop each level backward, if any id's in higher level then remove from array.

A couple of optimisation here too, eg. slice(0, -1), is so we don't need to create a SET for the last level, as were check previous ones.  Inside the loop once item is known to be deleted, use a break to then go onto next.  To be honest, I've no idea what the complexity on this is.. :)

eg.

```js
const arr_p1 = 
  [{ id: "892d" }, {id: "kla8x" }, {id: "sys32" }];
const arr_p2 = 
  [{id: "saa1" }, { id: "892d" }];
const arr_p3 = 
  [{ id: "kla8x" }, {id: "saa1" }, {id: "pp182" }];
  
  
function dedupe(alist) {
  const hasList = alist.map(
    m => new Set(m.slice(0, -1).map(i => i.id)));
  for (let l = alist.length -1; l > 0; l --) {
    for (let i = alist[l].length -1; i >= 0; i --) {
      for (let h = 0; h < l; h += 1) {
        if (hasList[h].has(alist[l][i].id)) {
          alist[l].splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


dedupe([arr_p1, arr_p2, arr_p3]);
console.log(arr_p1);
console.log(arr_p2);
console.log(arr_p3);
```